# $(input[]).each throwing syntax error in firefox only

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I am working on a web project and I am having a strange issue.

I have a textarea as follows:

```
<textarea style="margin-bottom: 5px" id="txtSupportDescription" name="txtSupportDescription[]" placeholder="Support Description" rows="10"></textarea>
```

I then have the following jquery

```
var supportComments = [];
$('textarea[name="txtSupportDescription[]"').each(function()
{
    supportComments.push($(this).val());
});
```

It works fine in Chrome and IE but in firefox I get the following error:

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ]" but its throwing the error in the jQuery library.

I don't understand why Firefox would have this issue when Chrome and IE are perfectly fine.

Comment: Got to escape those brackets: `$('textarea[name="txtSupportDescription\\[\\]"')`

Comment: @tymeJV Shouldn't the double quotes around the name make that unnecessary?

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic due to a typo.

Comment: From name textSupportDescription remove angle brackets and check if its ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a closing bracket "]" at the very end . Should be:

```
$('textarea[name="txtSupportDescription[]"]')
```

Comment: You might want to highlight which bracket was missing.

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe I missed that. Thanks

Comment: No problemo. Glad I could help!

Comment: @JonathanLonowski made a good point. I'll update my answer to help future peeps.